# How to convert WebArchive to HTML with images

Tags: objective-c, webkit

I have Safari's webarchive which need to convert to HTML with images.
How to implement it using objective c?

THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ur going to need Safari browser. I know my answer is not so good, but its the only way ***I KNOW***.

Here's the link:
[Safari Download](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/)

hope i helped you.

you can still doing it the old, boring way and copy the images into some web-editing software (like frontpage or any other just google it) and eventually save it.

------considering that you have a **Windows** operating system. if you have a Mac OS then Safari would be already installed-----